# R - Legend For Specific Points in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

Unfortunately, I think this is a tough item to reproduce, but I think the question should be simple enough to answer with a visual...

I'd like to build a legend for three specific dimensions in geom_point.

Any Hockey Fans Out There?

[image]

I'd like to build a legend for the dimensions that have colors on this chart. They are three different players I'd like to highlight, the rest of the points on the plot being general noise, but necessary for a visual.

In my opinion, here a legend would be more appealing than labels.

I know this is kind of ridiculous without being able to reproduce, but I hope the question is general enough (though I couldn't find an answer that satisfied what I was looking for) that it can be easily solved.

Happy to field questions.

Thanks!

Comment: yes, just put some text using `geom_text()` right by the points

Comment: Thanks for the response, Hubert! Unfortunately, I'm not looking to label the points on the chart. I'm looking to build a legend with the three highlighted players. Is there a way to build a legend with specific criteria and essentially ignore other plot points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved... the code looks like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
Offense <- read.csv("Offense1.csv")
plot <- ggplot(Offense[Offense$Gm>20,], aes(CF.Rel, SCF.Rel)) + geom_point() +
    geom_point(data=Offense[Offense$Name == "Eric.Staal",], aes(colour="Eric Staal"), size=4) +
    geom_point(data=Offense[Offense$Name == "Rick.Nash",], aes(colour="Rick Nash"), size=4) +
    geom_point(data=Offense[Offense$Name == "Tanner.Glass",], aes(colour="Tanner Glass"), size=4)
plot <- plot + labs(title = "Driving Offense", 
                x = "Relative Corsi For %", 
                y= "Relative Scoring Chances For %")
plot <- plot + scale_colour_discrete(name="Player")
plot
```

They key here was to make the aesthetic color the dimension you want to include in the legend.

[image]